# Invalid JSON primitive: System.Net.ConnectStream

Tags: c#

I'm trying to deserialize

```
  string strurlTest = String.Format("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments");
            WebRequest requestObjGet = WebRequest.Create(strurlTest);
            HttpWebResponse responseObjGet = null;

            responseObjGet = (HttpWebResponse)requestObjGet.GetResponse();

            string strresulttest = null;
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            using (Stream stream = responseObjGet.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
                strresulttest = sr.ReadToEnd();
  test t = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<dynamic>(res.ToString());
```

then I receive the error

> "Invalid Json Primitive"

please your support on it.
 Json data 
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments

Comment: While you don't define `res` anywhere in your code, it would appear that it's a `System.Net.ConnectStream` object that you have called `.ToString()` on. I'd try using your `strresulttest` object instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Test[] tests=  new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Test[]>(strresulttest );
```

use strresulttest instead of res. So your 'test' class should be like

```
    public class Test
    {
    public int postId { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string body { get; set; }
    }
```

Working solution as per comment

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            string strurlTest = String.Format("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments");
            WebRequest requestObjGet = WebRequest.Create(strurlTest);
            HttpWebResponse responseObjGet = null;

            responseObjGet = (HttpWebResponse)requestObjGet.GetResponse();

            string strresulttest = null;
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            using (Stream stream = responseObjGet.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
                strresulttest = sr.ReadToEnd();
                Test[] tests = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Test[]>(strresulttest);
            }

            return View();
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public int postId { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string body { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: thx for respond mate, I already tried with that and appear "Cannot implicitly convert type 'object[]' to 'WebApiConsumingTest.WebForm1.test'"

Comment: Check the sample code i posted and try to understand it before apply to your solution. Put more attention to Test class definition.